# Rails generate array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array and I want to generate an array with hash and inside that hash one more data. I have a data array which is:

```
   [
        {
        id: 1,
        name:"abc"
        title:"xyz"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name:"abc1"
        title:"xyz1"
        },
   ]
```

And I want to generate an output like this:

```
[
{        
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [
    {y: 1, label: "abc"},
    {y: 2 ,label: "xyz"}
     ]
},
{        
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [
    {y: 1, label: "abc1"},
    {y: 2 ,label: "xyz"}
    ]
 }         
]
```

How create this kind of array hash using map or any array loop. I am trying to generate data points for charts. I am looking for best possible solution.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as of now. Can you explain the logic of how to reach from input to output given in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options:

```
array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"abc",
    title:"xyz"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"abc1",
    title:"xyz1"
  }
]


[:name, :title].map do |column_name|
  { 
    type: 'column',
    dataPoints: array.map do |el| 
      { y: el[:id], label: el[column_name] }
    end
  }
end

# or in one line:

[:name, :title].map { |column_name| { type: 'column', dataPoints: array.map { |el| { y: el[:id], label: el[column_name] } } } }
```